# Properties disabled in scene builder

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder, gui-builder

This is where I can't change allignment and other properties and I don't know why:

[Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOf4p.png)

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines [MVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [what kinds of questions can I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, edit your question so that we may help.  Specifically, you need to include all relevant code and/or error messages **within the body of the question** so that if the **link** disappears, the question will still be valid and useful. The easier you make it for us to know the question, the better your chances of receiving an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

SceneBuilder won't let you edit properties which are overridden in CSS (hence the CSS icon).

You can add or remove scene stylesheets by going to `Preview > Scene Style Sheets`

To view which properties are overridden by CSS, you can press `CTRL+6` to bring up the CSS analyzer.

Answer (score 1):

In order for the icon to be displayed when you add it through the SceneBuilder, you must select the absolute path property.

version javafx: 8.0.211
version java: 1.8.0 build 211

[image]

It is not visible in my picture, but it must be selected.

[image]